# sort multiple files and merge

Tags: linux, sort, cat, merge, paste

I want to sort several text files in reverse order and then merge/cat to one single text file.

`a.txt`

```
0   33.1
2   33.0
10  21.1
20  21.8
```

`b.txt`

```
0   30.1
2   33.0
10  28.1
20  27.8
```

and so on `*.txt` files

I want output like this

```
20  21.8
10  21.1
2   33.0
0   33.1
20  27.8
10  28.1
2   33.0
0   30.1
```

I don't want like this

```
20  21.8
20  27.8
10  21.1
10  28.1
2   33.0
2   33.0
0   33.1
0   30.1
```

I tried these code

```
for file in *.txt ; do 
   sort -nrk 1,1 *.txt > "$file" ; 
done
```

and also I tried

```
sort -m *.txt
```

But the output from these codes is not I wanted.

I am looking for solutions using `sort` `merge` `paste` `cat` or some other relevant options.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort files individually, and redirect the whole output to the resulting file:

```
for file in *.txt ; do 
   sort -k1,1rn < "$file"
done > file.concatenated
```

(here it's important the output file doesn't have a `.txt` extension as it's created first by the redirection).

Or if you want to sort the files in place (rewriting them sorted over themselves):

```
set -- *.txt
ok=true
for file do
  sort -o "$file" -k1,1rn -- "$file" || ok=false
done
"$ok" && cat -- "$@" > file.concatenated
```

That two stage approach allows us to detect problems in the sorting of files before creating the concatenated file.

Your first loop didn't work as you were passing the full list of `.txt` files in each pass of the loop.

`sort -m` is to merge already sorted files into a sorted output. It's the opposite of what you want. You want to sort files that are not already sorted and just concatenate the results without merging them into a sorted output.

Here, the files seem to be sorted in forward order. If you can rely on that being always the case, you should be able to just reverse them which would be much more efficient than sorting them in reverse.

To do that, GNU systems have a `tac` command, and several others `tail -r` (though beware that some implementations only take one file argument, so you may need to resort to loop with those).

```
tac -- *.txt > file.concatenated
```

Also note that `-k1,1rn` is not the same as `-rnk1,1` when it comes to resolving ties. When two lines compare equally, `sort` resorts to a lexical comparison of the whole line (for instance here, `1 a` and `1 b` compare equally with `-k1,1n`, but `1 a` comes before `1 b` lexically).

With the `-r` option, that last resort comparison is done in reverse. That doesn't apply when a `r` flag is added to one of the key specifications.

GNU `sort` has `-s` to disable that last resort comparison which will cause it to preserve the original order of the lines that compare equally.

Comment: Excellent! Just as I needed. Also your second suggestion to sort in-place was also helpful. Thanks a bunch

Comment: @linux_lover, you're welcome. See also my `tac` addition in case your files are already sorted and you just  need to reverse them.

Comment: Thanks for that `tac` tip. What is the significance to two dashes `--` in `tac` and in the 'code to sort in place'?

Comment: @linux_lover see [What does "--" (double-dash) mean?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376). Here, the `*.txt` is expanded by the shell and the resulting files passed to `tac`, we want to make sure none of those file names are taken as options even if they start with `-` (`+` is also a problem for `sort`). It's good practice to use it when arguments are the result of some expansion (or rather, it's bad practice *not* to use it).

Comment: Thanks! That's a great info. Helped it.